# Creating certain queuing method for custom Priority Queue using Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparable, doubly-linked-list

I created the following add methods in my DoublyLinkedList class:

```
    /**
     * This method adds a DoublyLinkedNode at the end of the list.
     * @param element
     */
    public void add(E element) {
        DoublyLinkedNode <E>  newNode = new DoublyLinkedNode <E>(element);

        if (head == null) {
          head = tail = newNode; // The new node is the only node in list
        }
        else {
          tail.setNext(newNode); // Link the new with the last node
          tail = tail.getNext(); // tail now points to the last node
        }

        size++; // Increase size
      }

public void  add (int index,E element) {
  // Checking if index is out of bound and then throwing exception.
    if (index < 0 || index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index is out of bound.");
  // Checking if the list is empty and then adding the element to the head.
    if(head == null)
        head.setElement(element);
  // Creating a temporary node and assigning head to it.
    DoublyLinkedNode <E> tmp = head;
 // If the index exists in the first half then search starts from head.
    if(index <= size/2) {
        for(int i =0; i <index; i++)
            tmp = tmp.getNext();
    }

  // If the index exists in the second half then search starts from the tail.
    if(index > size/2) {
        tmp = tail;
        for(int i =size-1; i >index; i--)
            tmp = tmp.getPrevious();
        }
    // Setting the node element found at the index to the given element.
    tmp.setElement(element);

    }
```

Now I want to create a Priority Queue where least value element has the highest priority(opposite to conventional priority queue).I created my Priority Queue enqueue method the following way:

```
public class PriorityQueue <E extends Comparable <E>>
{
    private DoublyLinkedList <E> elements;
// ----------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Create a new PriorityQueue object.Inistantiates elements.
 */
public PriorityQueue() {
    elements = new DoublyLinkedList();
}

public void enqueue(E element) {
   /* for(int i =0; i < elements.size();i++)
   if(element.compareTo(elements.get(i))<0) */
    elements.add(element);
}
```

I really don't know if it's the right way to compare any given element in the queue to locate it's order and then add it to the queue.My intention is to read anything from a File and then output them in order.

Comment: neither of your `add` methods follows the rules of priority queue. do you actually know what is priority queue and how it is supposed to work?

Comment: Add methods are Doubly Linked List.I'm using priority queue using that.